# Acquiring $Df(\mathbf{x})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Sorry for the probably easy and silly question, but I try to teach myself linear algebra and I am stucked at "the derivative as a matrix" part. 
I know how to differentiate partially and I know how $Df(\mathbf{x})$ should look like. I just don't know how to calculate it with vectors/matrices. In the excercise I need to find $Df(\mathbf{x})$ at $a=\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\ 
2\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ with $f(\mathbf{x})=\begin{pmatrix}
(x+y)^3\\ 
x^2y^3\\ 
y/x\\
\end{pmatrix}$.
I don't understand the process... So could you please explain to me how it works?

I am using [these](http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/LAnotes/LAnotes.pdf) lecture notes (this part starts on p. 53).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, this is related to the *gradient* of a multivariable function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_and_the_derivative_or_differential if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the notes, if $f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}u_1(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \\ \vdots \\u_m(x_1, \ldots, x_m)\end{pmatrix}$, then 
$\text{D}f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} & \ldots & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} & \ldots & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix}$.

Here, $f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}(x + y)^3 \\ x^2y^3 \\ y/x\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}u(x, y)\\ v(x, y)\\ w(x, y)\end{pmatrix} \text{(say)}$

So $\text{D}f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}$

Can you find the answer now?

Then, to find $\text{D}f(a)$, evaluate the answer at $a = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ by substituting $x = 1, y = 2$.